# How to change datagrid cell's itemRenderer dynamically

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

i have a simple datagrid having 2 columns named as image and place. where image column has mx.controls.Image itemRenderer and place is simple. my requirement is to change itemRenderer of image cell when it will be clicked. i means to say when user click on any image from image column than i want to show that image path in editable mode and when user edit that path then the selected cell will start displayed the updated image.

i dont know how to do this and getting depressed . please anyone help me ! :(

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change itemRenderer for that - just implement that code in your single item renderer. You can add listeners inside it and change the contents of the current cell.

Comment: can u please give me example. i m new in flex.

Comment: sorry, guys, I'm no longer develop in Flex

Answer (score 0):

I suggest when going into editable mode for your DataGrid: Also create an itemEditor for your Image column, make it an extended TextInput class. This extended TextInput class will change the data object's imageAddress/url when you are done editing ("itemEditEnd" event).

Let me know if this helps, thanks!